# Java - State pattern: Using threads within the states

Tags: java, multithreading, state, state-machine

I want to coordinate serial requests coming from a Java Swing GUI using the state pattern. When a state method was called, the serial communication shall start and in parrallel the GUI should not be frozen during this time.

I have one GUI Thread. In this thread I'm invkoing methods of a state machine which also lives in the GUI Thread.
In some cases after a state machine method has been invoked, data from a serial port shall be fetched (longer task). This fetching is been done in an `otherThread`. On some state changes the `otherThread` can be interrupted and `otherThread` should stop immediately (I'm using  `otherThread.interrupt()`). To know when `otherThread` actually has returned, I use `otherThread.join()` to wait for `otherThread` in the GUI Thread.

Without using `join()` I always run into exceptions after a state change where I communicate via serial port in another `otherThread`.

The inconvinience of this approach is ofc. that the GUI thread is blocked/frozen as long as `otherThread` needs to finish its task.

I was thinking about calling the state machine method in a third thread. But I don't like this idea bcs.:

- I don't have a lot experience with multi threading in Java (I assume labeling the methods of the state machine as synchronized could work to ensure thread safetiness).
- Overhead due to thread and runnable creation for each invocation of a state machine method.

So my question is: What is a good way to make the GUI not frozen while waiting for otherThread?

Comment: The usual way to use multi-threading in a _Swing_ application is via class [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). Alternatively, you could use [JavaFX](https://openjfx.io/) rather than _Swing_.

Comment: But this would make my State machine dependent on a GUI framework which I would not like to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the stuff about "states", "state machines", and "state pattern" is red herring. (Meaning: it is completely irrelevant.) The question is simply how to avoid block-waiting for `Thread.join()` from the gui thread.

Your "otherThread" should be aware of the fact that it was interrupted and exit gracefully. (Look for more information on thread interruption in Java to see how to accomplish this correctly.)

Right before exiting, the "otherThread" should post a message back to your "gui thread" to let it know that it is exiting.

Posting a message back to the "gui thread" in Swing is done with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`, and the "message" is not exactly a message, it is a function that you pass to `invokeLater()` and it gets executed within the "gui thread".

Then, the "gui thread" can then either ignore the thread, or join with it, knowing that this `Thread.join()` will complete very quickly because thread termination is either imminent, or has already happened.

Comment: Re, "Then, the "gui thread" can...join with it,..." What would be the point of calling `t.join()` when you already know that thread `t` has finished its work? (I'm assuming that "knowing" means, you have established a chain of "happens before" relationships back to the completion of whatever it was that the thread was supposed to do.) Java is not like certain other languages in which "joining" releases resources that were used by the thread. In Java, the sole purpose of `t.join()` is to wait for confirmation that `t` is dead.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes, there is probably no point in joining other than perhaps a confirmation that things did indeed work according to plan, which is of marginal benefit.